# Is it ok to have 3 foreign keys in a table from one only table?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

So... Le's say I have 3 tables named:

1. **Member**
2. **Bus**
3. **AutorizeMember**

ID **Member** is referenced to **Bus** and ID **Bus** is referenced to **AutorizeMember** which is also referenced to **Member** 3 times. Thats is because there are some cases that a member in the **Bus** (which is the Bus' Owner) can select or not 3 others members who can drive the same bus.

[image: Demo database of the question]

So my question is: Is it ok to have 3 foreign keys from **Member** in **AutorizeMember**? In this way, is it normalize?

*I'm still new in this field so sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. Any opinion is helpful. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: It is unclear what your tables actually look like, it would be better to list exactly what fields they have, at least the ID and foreign key columns.

Comment: Could you make a basic diagram to show the tables and the link between them ? Sometimes a picture is better than a lots of words.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added a picture so it can help others to understand the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I got this correctly, you are thinking about introducing 3 foreign key attributes `MemberID1`, `MemberID2` and `MemberID3` into `AuthorizedMember` because you do want to model up to 3 members which might be authorized for driving.

This is usually not a good idea, because

- such requirements tend to change, next week someone wants up to allow 4 or 5 authorizations, or the number of authorization may depend on the bus type - and you don't want to change your data model whenever this happens
- code which is based on such repetitive attributes or keys tends to become repetitive by itself.

I guess what you really want is a link table (or junction table) `DrivingAuthorization` with two foreign keys `BusID` and `MemberID`. This models an [N:M relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between busses and members. Your application should make sure there will be no more authorizations per bus than allowed.

Let me add a note about your literal question: of course there are cases where  having three or more foreign keys between the same two tables ist justified - for expressing **different** kinds of relationships. For example, think of the table `Bus` and a `Person` table (where persons may include natural persons as well as organizations). There could be

- the main bus driver
- the conductor
- the bus owner

and for each one, I can imagine a foreign key referencing to the `Person` table.

Comment: If you are worried about the application being the place where the rule about having no more than 3 drivers per association lives, then you could also put logic into a Stored Procedure to add a driver, and do the <= 3 count there.

Comment: I have other question: Happens that i have the same issue as this [one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293385/table-with-2-columns-that-are-foreign-keys-only-one-can-be-set-for-every-record). Is it okay using this method or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: There are several ways to solve such requirements. One needs to provide some semantical context to make sensible decisions about data modeling like providing an example as you did it here in this question.

Comment: Thanks again. I will make a question about it because I got a couple tables that need the same resolution or at least so I think.