# How to set only one foreign key for every record where the table has 2 foreign keys?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I know that this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293385/table-with-2-columns-that-are-foreign-keys-only-one-can-be-set-for-every-record) has been asked before and is the same or at least almost the same but I just want to know: Is it the only method or is there any other way to do it?

I have these tables: `Person1` and `Person2` are referenced to `User`:
[image: Tables of User, Person1 and Person2]

At the moment of insereting a new user, it's only posible to inset one `ID_Person` but not both which means that both of the foreign keys are optional.

Is this the only one way or is there any other way?

*I'm still new in this field so sorry if I didn't explain myself correctly. Any opinion is helpful. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: So what is the issue that needs to be solved?

Comment: Can any single person record be associated with more than one user?

Comment: you can have null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, your foreignkeys are not settable for all the records, so they need to be optional(**nullable**) for the Main Table that references them.